# Tensorflow Shape rank error for DrawBoundingBoxes

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I trained an object detector with Tensorflow 1.15, and now I'm trying to run it on individual images to see for myself if it works. However, when running my test code I get this error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Shape must be rank 4 but is rank 3 for 'DrawBoundingBoxes' (op: 'DrawBoundingBoxes') with input shapes: [235,339,3], [1,300,4].
```

This occurs at this line in the code:

```
tf.image.draw_bounding_boxes(image, boxes)
```

I think my issue is that I need to reshape either my boxes or my image, but I'm not sure which I should change, nor how I should do it as I'm new to Tensorflow. I can provide more of the code if necessary. Here's the link to the
[Tensorflow object detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) which I've followed as close as possible through the process of training my network.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seemed to be that I wasn't passing a color argument. Adding that fixed the error.